# os.chroot Operation not permitted

Tags: python, linux, chroot

I'm trying to write a python script to generate a debian package.
I'm generating required folder structure in a temporary folder. In order to change uid and gid of /usr and subfolders to root I thought of using chroot.

However, on this line

```
os.chroot(tmpdir)
```

I get:

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/tmpVnTqW7/myproj'
```

I've also tried this mini-tutorial with same results: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chroot.htm

Why would that be?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

chroot() can be done only by root.

do one of these:

1. Run the script with sudo
2. Make the script setuid root, and do the setuid(geteuid()) equivalent python magic

Answer (score 1):

> I'm generating required folder structure in a temporary folder. In order to change uid and gid of /usr and subfolders to root I thought of using chroot.

I am not sure if you are on the right track. I don't know much about `.deb` packages, but in `.rpm` packages, you can define in the file list which file properties to assign to which files.

So you don't set them in the file system, but just tell the system what should happen.

As said, this counts for `.rpm`; I'm not sure if it is the same in `.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chrootting to the directory you should use fakeroot to execute dpkg-deb: fakeroot dpkg-deb -z8 -Zgzip --build myproj